# Is a law of nature a universal?

Tags: aristotle, plato, philosophy-of-physics

Newton described his theory of gravity as universal. I take this to mean that this theory was universally valid, that it brought together both terrestrial and celestial phenomena under one rubric. It made no distinction between types of matter - all matter behaved in the same way.

However, given the times he lived in another possibility presents itself, and this is that a law of nature is a *universal*, and that it instantiates itself in matter as we see it.

Has this option been followed up by anyone? I mean discussing the laws of nature through Plato's theory of forms? Also is this the sense that Aristotle means that form and matter come together in his notion of hylomorphism?

Comment: See [Laws of Nature : Universals](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/laws-of-nature/#Uni) for modern point of view.

Comment: [Universals](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/universals-medieval/#2) is a medieval concept, strongly related to Plato's Forms and A's essence;  but - at that time - scarcely linked to the not-yet-formulated idea of "law of nature". *Gravitation* is not an universal in medieval sense...

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA: First, I think its well to recall that Newton isn't a modern in any way; one reason I wrote this question, is that I looked at something written by Newton which showed that he had read Aristotle, and there was a hint of 'forms' determining the 'ether'; basically he asked the question why are atoms 'ponderable'; I'll see if i can dig up the extract as I've forgotten where I saw it...

Comment: Thanks by the way for the reference - however its not the angle I'm taking;  there is, after all, in philosophy of mathematics a position called mathematical platonism, I'm asking is whether there is something similar in the physical sciences; it seems strange to me, that there can be this position in mathematics, and given that physics is dependent on mathematics for description, that there wouldn't have been any thought investigating this line of thought; having said that, this is not quite what I'm asking about.

Comment: Yes, there is, one could call it physical Platonism or Pythagoreanism. Penrose https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orchestrated_objective_reduction#Details and Tegmark are recent examples https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_universe_hypothesis Both face serious epistemological problems, not unlike Plato's own.

Comment: @conifold: not really relevant; Plato wasn't against poets per se, as so often said, for example in his *Republic*, and elsewhere; what he was against was *imitativeness*; and in the *Laws*, against *corruption*...

Comment: And here we see ideas becoming corrupted...

Comment: Before asking what Newton intended (and how could we know what he intended?), we must first answer this question: Is there a difference between (1) _universal_ in the realist, anti-nominalist sense and (2) _universal_ in the sense of "predicable of everything"? It seems not because isn't that the definition of _universal_?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Who first "formulated [the] idea of 'law of nature'"? How exactly is that idea different from the what the medievals thought (cf. "[X. Physical Laws](https://www3.nd.edu/~maritain/jmc/etext/physic.htm)" from Cornoldi's [_The Physical System of St. Thomas_](https://www3.nd.edu/~maritain/jmc/etext/physic10.htm))?

Comment: @Geremia - for the modern idea of *Law of nature*, see Descartes' [Principia, 2, XXXVII](https://books.google.it/books?id=JQs_AAAAcAAJ&pg=PA43):"Prima lex nature", etc.; the source of Newton's laws. In Galileo there are no "laws" explicitly called so.

Comment: About medieval phil, I'm not an expert, but I do not think that we can find explicit formulation of some physical law (neither a "wrong" one, i.e. one subsequently discarded with the progress of physical knowledge).

Comment: For sure N knows some of A (as any "learned guy" of his time)... How much, I do not know. Maybe a search into : [Unpublished Scientific Papers of Isaac Newton : A Selection from the Portsmouth Collection in the University Library, Cambridge](https://books.google.it/books?id=IvkzAAAAIAAJ&pg=PR9) (1962).

Comment: For what I know the concept of "universal" was firstly "invented" by Plato to answer the paradigmatic Socratic question about the *definition* of e.g. *good* or *virtue* : "what is ..." (*ti estì*). Plato's answer is : all good things share "the Good" (the Form). In Newtonian physics all bodies have *mass*; but it seems to me hard to say that there is some sort of "Mass-ness" that all bodies partake of...

Comment: I wasn't referring to poets, but to the relations between universals, let alone law-universals, to the particulars that they are supposed to govern, and to the cognizing subjects. "Imitation" didn't really work, and neither did anamnesis. This is why Aristotle had to put universals back into particulars as "secondary substances", and dissolve the ideal realm. Penrose and Tegmark wish to have the realm back, but without addressing its epistemological issues.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA [Galileo commentated on Aristotle's _Posterior Analytics_ logical treatise](https://isidore.co/calibre/browse/book/5067), but Newton disregarded Aristotle (as a search [here](http://www.newtonproject.sussex.ac.uk/prism.php?id=139) reveals). Also, Newton thought space (not mass) was God.

Comment: But as I see it, this depends on what do we mean by "universal" and "law of nature". In all cases we can produce such a statment that can be true, but adding "it's universally true that ..." will be redundant. For example, "Some people are males" and "It's universally true that some people are males". You can put universal quantifier on every statement without changing the meaning. But then I dunno if the question in itself makes sense.

Comment: @rus9384: Well, I'm taking Newtons law of gravity as paradigmatic of a universal law of nature - do you have a different suggestion? I'd consider that to be a superficial criticism; it's obviously possible to add redundant qualifiers that do not change the meaning - and that's one of the distinctions between syntax and semantics.

Comment: The fact is that we don't know if Newton's laws are really universal. Even inside the observable universe alone. So, if it turns out it's false, we must say that only under certain circumstances Newton's laws are true. Then these laws could be universal. That's what I meant. Or do you mean if it turns out they are false, we must say they are not laws of nature?

Comment: @rus9584: To put it in really simple terms: for example if I said I had a black cat as a pet; and then I said I had a black black cat as a pet, or even a black black black black black cat as a pet; then those additional qualifiers do not change the sense of the sentence.

Comment: @rus4894: Sure, and that's where philosophy as in the philosophy of nature comes in; I asked a question whether we could justify the existence of universal laws and gave an argument for such.

Comment: Okay, it makes sense if existential quantifiers are not allowed because we always can add one to the beginning. But then I must say that natural laws may be not universal, they only should be valid sentences, like in math.

Comment: @rus9384: That need not be true of just existential qualifiers - it depends on the structure of the sentence. That's an assertion not an argument; it's pretty well known that mathematical logic is something of an isolated island on that continent or archipelago called mathematics. Mathematics has such things as existence proofs - you can view a philosophical argument for universal laws as a kind of analogue - a philosophical existence proof; having said that, it's one thing to assert that there are such things as universal physical laws - it's quite another to find them.

Comment: Can you please clarify your question? We know that Newton's formulas aren't *quite* correct - Einstein's work revised them significantly (General Theory of Relativity, or GR), and the incompatibilities between GR and QM (Quantum Mechanics) suggest that GR may also be an incomplete description of reality.  Since Newton's "Laws" of Universal Gravitation are themselves incomplete, how does this affect your usage of the word "Universal" in your question?

Answer (score 1):

When something is said to be, say, a ***universal*** fact, belief, natural response, etc., this distinction applies ONLY to the **material universe**, or that sphere of existence governed by the laws of Newtonian physics.

Any realm outside the boundaries or scope of the physical universe, whether known or unknown, discovered or as yet to be discovered, is NOT limited by the finite laws that, to date, are universally recognized and accepted parameters defined by and within the visible world in which humans exist.

I’m NOT saying that there are no consistent elements that are applicable in every aspect of spheres outside the known boundaries of the universe, just that the term “universal” is specific to our universe.

Comment: I made an edit which you may roll back or continue editing.  You can see the versions in the "edited" link above. One thing you might add is any reference to someone taking the same position that you do. This would give the reader a change to get more information and strengthen your answer. +1 and welcome.

Answer (score 1):

I will try to summarize what should be a general consensus (more or less). We would first have to define our terms: "law of nature" and "universal".

#### Two different types of "laws of nature"

There are *two* distinct things that are called *laws of nature*, that one tends to confuse, but:

1. The first type is a human creation: it's expressed in symbols, diagrams, etc. It belongs to the field of **mathematics**, and when applied, it belongs to the field of **physics** and **engineering**.
2. The second type is of a different order: it is postulated (in **philosophy**) that there exists some form of organization in the universe -- in the time of Newton it was conceived as a "clockwork" -- and that this organization follows a definite pattern.

Why are these two things distinct? Because science moved from pre-Newtonian to Newtonian mechanics, and then discovered other phenomena (e.g. electromagnetic), as well as relativistic and quantum mechanics, etc. And each time, the mathematical representation changed and it will change.

By contrast we assume that the philosophical law of nature -- of which the mathematical one is our best approximation -- is unchanged and exists independently of our understanding and, presumably, our very existence as humans (*though there can exist philosophies that deny existence to the physical universe outside of human perception*).

The assumption is that we are trying to **approximate** those laws with increasing accuracy.

#### What do we mean by universal?

I assume that by **universal** you mean:

> Of, relating to, or affecting the entire universe: *the universal laws of physics*. ([American Heritage](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=universal))

The relation between universal and the *universe* as we understand it today is not obvious, since Webster's 1828 definition did not express things in this fashion:

> 1. All; extending to or comprehending the whole number, quantity or space; as universal ruin; universal good; universal benevolence.
>
> *The universal cause acts not by partial, but by general laws*.

In that case, it meant "applicable to everything", in a philosophical sense. By which it meant litterally *everything*. So let's call it (just for the sake of this here discussion) **generalized universality**.

The problem is, what people at the time of Newton conceived as universe (the sun and a few stars), progressively expanded into massive number of stars, a galaxy, other galaxies, clusters of galaxies, etc.

This expansion of our horizons was humourously summarized by Douglas Adamas (The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy) as:

> Space is big. You just won't believe how vastly, hugely, mind- bogglingly big it is. I mean, you may think it's a long way down the road to the chemist's, but that's just peanuts to space.

In this early 21st century, it's even worse, because we incrasingly tend to make a distinction between this universe and other possible ones, with **multiverses**:

> The collection of parallel universes that comprise all of reality in some quantum mechanical and cosmological theories. ([American Heritage](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=multiverse))

It stands to reason that there those universes exist in a different physical [continuum](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=continuum) (otherwise it would be the same universe). But it is also speculated that laws of nature might be different in an other universe.

Hence we might be prudent and think, philosophically, of a **restricted universality** of natural laws (our universe).

#### About Newton's Laws

So Newton might have thought that the laws in the *Principia Mathematica* were universal.

- Today we might consider that **Newton laws are universal in a restricted sense**, because gravity seems to work in a uniform way throughout the universe (but who knows what those rules might be in another random universe).
- But there is a caveat that **they are not universal even for this universe**, because we know now that they break down in a variety of cases, particulalry when masses or speeds are very high -- which we know now is a problem for orbits close to the Sun, or when you want to calculate a position with GPS.

So without going into the depth of Ancient or early eighteenth century metaphysics, or the atheist-creationist slanging matches, the **compromise in purely physical sciences** is just that the **question of ideas (theory of forms, etc.) or spirituality** is not necessary to solutions of the problems of physical laws concerning chemistry, mechanics, astrophysics, etc.

Nevertheless I would say that **yes**, it is conceived that there is some kind of inner structure of the observable universe, which then leaves anyone the freedom of metaphysical interpretation.

Henri Poincaré noted (in the [preface](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Science_and_Hypothesis/Introduction) of *Science and Hypothesis*, 1905) that:

> The method of the physical sciences is based upon the induction which leads us to expect the recurrence of a phenomenon when the circumstances which give rise to it are repeated.

It's an *induction* (trying to go from the particular to the general) and *expecting a recurrence* (so that same conditions would lead to same happening). It is implicit that people who work in physical sciences assume that there is that kind of recurrence, which is (*hypothetically*, but assumed certain for all practical purposes) **universal**.

The bottom line is that there is, within the confines of our science, no mathematical representation of natural law that is universal. But we like to assume, philosophically *and* because it is practical for everyday purposes, that there is a system of natural law in the cosmos.

#### The problem of the expansion of our understanding

The concept of multiverses postulates that different conditions exist in different universes. Of course if one was able to make a consistent "theory of everything" that would describe whatever existed in *any* universe then would assume some sort of **generalized universality**... but that would a giant leap into speculation (or hypothesis).

And supposing that such a theory of multiverses could exist and considering the continuous expansion of our sensory and intellectual horizons, who knows that it would not break down once again in some corner?

We could find various quotes about this problem, e.g. Richard Feynman (1918-1988) [emphasis added]:

> - Are you looking for the ultimate laws of physics?"
> - No, I'm not. I'm just looking to find out more about the world and **if it turns out there is a simple ultimate law which explains everything, so be it**; that would be very nice to discover. If it turns out it's like an onion with millions of layers and we're just sick and tired of looking at the layers, then that's the way it is. ... My interest in science is to simply find out more about the world.”

I guess that this "modesty of hypotheses" is a predominant applied philosophy in the scientific community today.